# Count tabs in empty end of line

Tags: java, split, count

I dont know if my question makes sense or not, but i am facing this problem

Case 1:

```
String fileLine  ="->->->6";
System.out.println(fileLine.split("\t").length);

output: 4
```

Case 2:

```
String fileLine  ="1->->->6";
System.out.println(fileLine.split("\t").length);

output: 4
```

The Problem Case:

```
String fileLine  ="1->6->->";
System.out.println(fileLine.split("\t").length);

output: 2
```

Can anyone tell me why is that and to capture this situation?

I want to capture the tabs in the end of the line as well even if the file end is empty

Thanks

Comment: [Always read the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)): "Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array." Use `split("\t", -1)` instead.

Comment: thanks Andy i could not find the exact word to search for that question thanks for guiding..